# Porting Android 5 to old device

Tags: android, porting, rom

As you read on the question title, I would like to port android latest version, or at least, one of the latest one to my old tablet which runs a rk3066 cpu with 1gb of ram and 16gb of nand.

I have the decompiled update.img of my manufacturer with android version 4.1.1, kernel and boot images, their ramdisk content,...

I have the source code and sdk of rk3066 based development board with android 4.4.4

I have Google's official Android 5 source code.

How should I start to port Android 5 to my tablet, making an usable and bootable custom ROM?

Comment: do you have any previous experience in porting rom?

Comment: Not exactly in porting because I never did it before, but I know how to build from source, edit and add new features to a downloaded cyanogen rom, as an example.

Comment: your question doesn't belong to this site. You should ask this on stack exchange Android Enthusiast site